# Error in checking variable in while loop

Tags: tcl

I am trying to check the value of a variable in a while loop

```
 set resultReturn 0
 while {expr $resultReturn == 0} {
    # Apply the stream configurations.
    set resultReturn [stc::apply]
 }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
syntax error in expression "expr $resultReturn == 0": variable references require preceding $
```

What should be the correct way to check the variable in an infinite loop until it changes value from 0?

Comment: Though given your error message, I would check `resultReturn` and make sure you are getting a valid numeric value back.

Answer (score 3):

While takes a test as its first argument and processes it in the same manner as `expr`.

```
while { $resultReturn == 0 } {
```

References: [while](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)